# What for a sequence is this?

Tags: sequences-and-series

With some algorithm I have come upon the following sequence with integer numbers $n$:

$$\dfrac{n-2}{n}$$

or the sequence

$$\dfrac{2}{n}$$

(Does not really matter).

What is this for a sequence? Is it a solution to some mathematical, logical, or other problem?

As a matter of fact, I should note that for n=2 my algorithm does *not* give `0` (or `1`), but `1/4` instead (or `3/4`).

Comment: I don't think so, but I might be wrong.

Comment: I mean, this is $1-2\cdot\frac{1}{n}$ and $1/n$ is a HIGHLY used sequence for building examples, counter-examples etc... It might be one of the most used sequences I guess. $1/n$ is also the solution to the problem: there are $n$ person wanting to share a cake equitably. What portion of the cake will have each person ?

Comment: What is special about $2$ in your mind?  Why this and not $(n-1)/n$, for example?

Comment: I do not know what is so special about the '2'. Its just that my algorithm gives this sequence...

Answer (score 3):

This is the angle of a regular polygon with $n$ vertices and sides expressed as a fraction of 180 degrees.

**Example:** A triangle has 3 sides, so the angle would be $\frac{1}{3} \cdot 180^\circ = 60^\circ$, which is true.

Comment: This is interesting...